# Double versus float

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

I have a constant for pi in my code:

`const float PI = acos(-1);`

Would it be better to declare it as a double?  An answer to another question on this site said floating point operations aren't exactly precise, and I'd like the constant to be accurate.

Comment: wouldn't math.h's M_PI be better?

Comment: "... the decimal representation of π truncated to 39 decimal places is sufficient to estimate the circumference of any circle that fits in the observable universe with precision comparable to the radius of a hydrogen atom." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi

Comment: @sje397: This is a _really_ cool comparison!

Comment: The `math.h` standard header in C defines a lot of constants to the required precision as the Unix98 standard decrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From standard:**

> There are three ﬂoating point types:
>   float, double, and long double. The
>   type double provides at least as much
>   precision as float, and the type long
>   double provides at least as much
>   precision as double.

Of the three (notice that this goes hand in hand with the 3 versions of `acos`) you should choose `long double` if what you are aiming for is precision (but you should also know that after some degree, further precision may be redundant in some cases).

So you should use this to get the most precise result from `acos`

```
long double result = acos(-1L);
```

(Note: There might be some platform specific types or some user defined types which provide more precision)

Comment: I think you meant to use acosl() instead of acos().

Answer (score 8):

"precise" is not a boolean concept. `float` provides a certain amount of precision. Whether or not that amount is sufficient for your application depends on, well, your application.

*most* applications don't need more precision than `float` provides, though many prefer to use `double` to (try and) gloss over problems with unstable algorithms or "just because" due to misconceptions like "floating point operations aren't exactly precise".

In most cases when a `float` is "not precise enough", the problem is not `float`, it's the code that uses it.

**Edit:** That being said, most modern CPUs only do calculations in `double` precision or greater anyway, so you might as well use `double` unless you're working with large arrays and memory usage is an issue.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: on my platform, `float` has about 5-6 digits worth of precision. `double` nicely goes up to 11-12 digits. For monetary amounts, I prefer to use `double`...

Comment: Actually, most prefer double because it is the "default" precision (0.0 is a double literal, to get float you'd do 0.0f).

Comment: Matthieu: IEEE float/double/long double have 6/15/18 decimal digits worth of precision. And for monetary values, you should use fixed-point arithmetic.

Comment: @Matthieu: For monetary amounts (at least the kind that actually ends up as a position in an account), you should use a proper decimal type. Everything else is amateurish crap.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: I would prefer the fixed point... but it wasn't up to me :/

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like the constant to be accurate.

There is nothing like accurate floating point values. They cannot be stored with perfect precision, because of their representation in memory. This is only possible with integers. `double` give you double the precision a `float` offers (who would have guessed). `double` should fit your needs in almost every case.

I would recommend using `M_PI` from `<cmath>`, which should be available in all POSIX compliant implementations of the standard.

Comment: It's `<cmath>`, and M_PI is not standard, but available on most compilers.

Comment: So M_PI is an accurate integer representation of Pi then?

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: No. PI has no accurate representation. The most powerful supercomputers on this planet are still calculating this number. @rubenvb: POSIX compliant implementations should have `M_PI` defined.

Comment: @elusive: of course it has. positional notation isn't th only way to represent numbers, you know.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: Yes, but C++ does not support that kind of number representation. You'll have to deal with it using `double`, `long double` or `float`. `int` is very inaccurate, since you'd only get `3` to fit in there.

Comment: Contrary to your statement, some non-integers may be stored with perfect precision.  Obvious examples include 0.5, 1.75, 1/64.  Only numbers that can be expressed as a finite power-of-two series have a chance to be both accurately and precisely expressed as a floating point value.

Comment: @elusive: The most powerful supercomputers do have more important things to do than computing PI. We already know PI to more digits than we ever need. According to wikipedia, we almost reached 2.7 trillion digits in january 2010.

Comment: @elusive: PI has an accurate representation (usually called π or "PI", and there a languages which are actually able to do further computations with this kind of representation), but no accurate representation in any float point format

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly *how* precise you need to be. I've never had to you doubles because floats are not precise enough.

**The most accurate representation of pi is `M_PI` from `math.h`**

Answer (score 1):

The question boils down to: how much accuracy do you need?

Let's [quote wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Decimal_representation):

> For example, the decimal
>   representation of π truncated to 11
>   decimal places is good enough to
>   estimate the circumference of any
>   circle that fits inside the Earth with
>   an error of less than one millimetre,
>   and the decimal representation of π
>   truncated to 39 decimal places is
>   sufficient to estimate the
>   circumference of any circle that fits
>   in the observable universe with
>   precision comparable to the radius of
>   a hydrogen atom.

I've written a [small java program](http://pastebin.com/R4WEjR1C), here's its output:

```
As string: 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
As double: 3.141592653589793
As float:  3.1415927
```

*Remember*, that if you want to have the double precision of a *double*, all your numbers you're calculating with need also to be *doubles*. <sub>(That is not entierly true, but is close enough.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/acos/) site says, there are three overloaded versions of acos function.

Therefore the call acos(-1) is ambiguous.

Having said that, you should declare PI as long double to avoid any loss of precision, by using

```
   const long double PI = acos(-1.0L);
```

Comment: It's not ambiguous, it will get you the double version (there are rules for that in the c++ standard)

Answer (score 0):

For most applications, float would do just fine for PI.  Double is definitely has more precision, but it doesn't guarantee precision anymore than floats can.  By that I mean that the number 1.0 represented in binary is not a rational number.  Therefore, if you try to represent it, you'll only succeed to an nth digit where n is determined by how many bytes you use to represent that number.

Unfortunately to contain many digits of PI, you'd probably need to hold it in a string.  Though now we're talking about some impressive number crunching here that you might see in molecule simulations.  You're probably *not* going to need that level of precision.